# How to manipulate pages content inside Webkit window (Using QT and QTWebKit)?

Tags: qt, macros, webkit

Please help me to understand, how can I manipulate html content which is shown inside qt webkit window. I need simple operations like filling in input fields and clicking a button. Any tips/article on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pls check an example below. It uses [QWebView](http://chaos.troll.no/~tavestbo/webkit/domapi/qwebview.html) to load the google page. Then uses QWebFrame class to find web elements corresponding to the search edit box and "google search" button. Edit box gets updated with a search query and then the search button gets clicked.

Load page:

```
QWebView::connect(ui->webView, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(on_pageLoad_finished(bool)));
QUrl url("http://www.google.com/");
ui->webView->load(url);
```

on_pageLoad_finished implementation:

```
void MainWindow::on_pageLoad_finished(bool ok)
{
    if (ok)
    {
        QWebFrame* frame = ui->webView->page()->currentFrame();
        if (frame!=NULL)
        {
            // set google seatch box
            QWebElementCollection collection = frame->findAllElements("input[name=q]");
            foreach (QWebElement element, collection)
                element.setAttribute("value", "how-to-manipulate-pages-content-inside-webkit-window-using-qt-and-qtwebkit");
            // find search button
            QWebElementCollection collection1 = frame->findAllElements("input[name=btnG]");
            foreach (QWebElement element, collection1)
            {
                QPoint pos(element.geometry().center());
                // send a mouse click event to the web page
                QMouseEvent event0(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
                QApplication::sendEvent(ui->webView->page(), &event0);
                QMouseEvent event1(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
                QApplication::sendEvent(ui->webView->page(), &event1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

hope this helps, regards