# how to navigate to another page using QMouseEvent qt event

Tags: qt, webkit

Please help me , I need to load one page then simulating click event to get the content of the target page. from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034981/how-to-manipulate-pages-content-inside-webkit-window-using-qt-and-qtwebkit) tutorial I figured out how to produce the event but how do I actually getting the QWebPage reference to the next page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does `QApplication::postEvent` with your event and QWebView as target works as suposed?

Comment: nop, I get the first page content not the second (the target)

Comment: So maybe I didn't understand what you want to achieve. You want to get contents of url target page into what? Into Pixmap ? Specify your question